# $ is not defined in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

I've included jQuery in my page in head tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But Chrome says that code which uses jQuery is incorrect and I see the error "$ is not defined":

```
$(".product").on('click', function() {

    var cv = $(this).attr("id");

    $.get("cvs/cv"+cv+".html", function(text){ 
        $(".about").html(text);
    });

});
```

But this code works in Mozilla Firefox. What's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Did you check another jquery version in your HTML file? may be conflicted

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for `$( document ).ready()`?

Comment: So, the problem was in "http" in jQuery's link and my page was loaded with https, so stupid mistake... Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Always try to include your external scripts before the end of the `body` tag NOT in the `head` tag. because the document needs to be loaded the read the scripts

example:

```
<body>
 ...
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".product").on('click', function() {

        var cv = $(this).attr("id");

        $.get("cvs/cv"+cv+".html", function(text){ 
            $(".about").html(text);
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Also the below link helps you and has more descriptions

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, please check there is another jQuery library included.
And please try this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".product").on('click', function(){
        //Your code
    });
});
```